# Many-to-many is Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing backend for trello-clone app using Rails. I have board entity which has many column entities which are having many cards entities. I've made board-column part (using blog app example) and it works fine, but I can't understand how to make column-card part of that.
Method create in card controller is like:

```
def create
 @board = Board.find(params[:board_id])
 @column = @board.columns.find(params[:column_id])
 @card = @column.cards.create(card_params)
end
```

I've made the form like this for adding cards for each column :
[image: card adding form]

Form code:

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @column.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Color:</strong>
  <%= @column.background_color %>
</p>

<h2>Add a card:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [@board, @column, @column.cards.build], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :description %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

So my question is how to make normal entity adding for the second level of the many-to-many relationship?

Comment: For me this sounds like the basic knowledge about how things work is missing, so I suggest to read about associations on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html as they have it well described there. If this does not help, maybe try to describe what you tried and how you think it should work so we can point you into the right direction.

Comment: What does your new action look like? That will set up the object for your form

Comment: When you pass an array of models (variables that is) to form, your params are not simpler like you are accessing in controller. It becomes a different hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous but I guess you probably are confused about this thing:

Add `hidden_field` for `board_id` like:

```
  form.hidden_field :board_id, value: @board.id
```

Then access it in the controller update/create with something like `params[:column][:board_id]` (check params to be exact) and relate the column with  board id.

**You surely are missing this piece but you surely are missing more.**

I would suggest using `byebug` gem and inspecting params hash. It will help you a lot because I think you need to inspect params which are confusing you.

Another way (not good but simpler) to

```
puts "*"*100
puts params
puts "*"*100
```

as first line of create action in controller to see how exactly your params are. (Go into console and find whatever is written between 2 lines of asterisks in your server console)

**Good Luck!**